# Viewport render image > How to render custom background color?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I want to render my viewport. I know how to do that.

I also know how to change the background color of the viewport.

Unfortunately both solutions i know (gradient color in preferences and this guy here:

[image]

won't be rendered.

Is it possible at all to render the viewport background color somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work just fine.
This is the way I do it:

1. Viewport shading overlay > Background > Viewport (adjust to your needs)
2. View > Viewport Render Image
3. Done

[image]

Comment: thank you. i did that. you are totally right. you couldn't know i had the transparent flag checked :( works now

Comment: Glad you made it work :). Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!